# What is the wrong with my code? MIN is not showing

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxMin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the arrays value : ");
        int userInput = myScanner.nextInt();

        int[] myArray = new int[userInput];

        System.out.println("please enter the values for arrays : ");

        int sum = 0;
        int max = myArray[0];
        int min = myArray[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = myScanner.nextInt();
            sum = sum + myArray[i];
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (max < myArray[i]) {
                max = myArray[i];
            }

            if (min > myArray[i]) {
                min = myArray[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is : " + sum + " \nmax is : " + max + "\nmin is : " + min);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT------------------------------

Please enter the arrays value : 
5
please enter the values for arrays : 
5
63
23
58
6
The sum is : 155 
max is : 63
min is : 0 // why 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Your code is performing correctly. Given you input `"5 63 23 58 6"` the min of your *array* is `0`, because your array is size `5` (as entered), but you only input `4` elements, leaving the last element at with (default) value of `0`)

Comment: which would be immediately obvious with 2 seconds in the step debugger

Comment: You need to initialize `min` and `max` variables **after** you have inserted values in the array. Just move `int max = myArray[0]; int min = myArray[0];`
after first for loop;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned `min` and `Max` to `myArray[0]` before actually taking input of myArray values.

As `myArray` has default of zero min is assigned to zero.